# Updating the median when removing an element from a list

Tags: algorithm, median

You are given a list of mixed integers from 1 to n (with no duplicates) say 4,2,6,1,5,3 and the sorted list 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Now the median is 3.5. This is can be calculated in O(1) time when looking at the sorted list 1,2,3,4,5,6. Now remove 4 from the mixed list. Is there an algorithm to update the median in O(1) time? I thought of removing index 4-1=3 from the sorted list and finding the median of that.

This works for the first iteration but not the rest ie when you remove 2, 6 and so on. What I'm wondering if there exists an algorithm for updating the median given that you know:

- The previous median
- The integer that has been removed from the list
- The number of iterations

Comment: 1. You can remove the element from the list in O(N) time.
2. It's possible to use Binary Search tree, and perform insert/delete operations in O(logN) time and find the median in O(logN) time also).

Comment: calculating the media is `O(n)`, not `O(1)`. You have to look at all elements to calculate the median. The median can only be calulated in `O(1)`, if the list was a row of the kind `[x , x + n , x + n * 2 , ...].

Comment: @SashaMN: for that you need a balanced BST.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not exactly balanced, balanced - too strong assumption.

Comment: @SashaMN: who said anything about "exactly"?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath balanced means: len(longest path) - len(shortest path) <= 1. And this is too strong assumption. You can ask only that len(longest path) must be O(logN).

Comment: @SashaMN: no, it doesn't mean that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: @KarolyHorvath key word here "Self-balancing". Not "balanced".

Comment: @SashaMN: oops wrong term. Thank you!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that was tricky thing. For example, AVL-tree is balanced, but RB-tree only self-balancing tree.

Answer (score 2):

I know 2 ways how efficiently solve this problem.

First algorithm:

1. Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

You can modify this tree (insert or delete elements) in O(logN) time.

Just perform Select(size / 2) operation to find the median. This is
    O(logN) solution.

2. Maintain two binary heaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

First heap will contain first size / 2 smallest elements, and keep the maximum in the root.

Second heap will contain last size / 2 biggest elements, and keep the minimum in the root.

Now you can find the median as the root element in the first or in the second heap.

To perform delete (or insert) operation, you can delete the element from the first or second heap (depends on element).

Now, if size(first heap) == size(second heap) + 2, you can remove the maximum from the first heap, and insert to second heap.

If size(first heap) + 2 == size(second heap), you can remove the minimum from the second heap and insert it to first heap.

All this operations take O(logN) time.